# Grails 3 run interceptors before filters

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-filters

In Grails 3, it seems the filters are running before the interceptors. 
I was wondering is it possible to make the interceptors run before the filters? 
I am aware the filters are deprecated and we started the transition to interceptors.

Comment: No it's not possible because of the way interceptors are implemented within the framework.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. This helps a lot.

Comment: @ShiranR can you answer the question yourself by taking Josuhas comment in order to close your question?

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Moore's answer: No it's not possible because of the way interceptors are implemented within the framework.